# Probability question please guide

Tags: probability

There are $5$ red and $3$ blue chips in a bowl. The red ones are numbered $1,2,3,4,5$ and the blue ones as $1,2,3$ respectively. if $2$ chips are drawn without repacement, find the probability that these chips have either the same number or the same colour.

What i think ::

For same colour, for the blue ones it will be $\binom{5}{1}*\binom{4}{1}$ and for the red ones $\binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}$. So total would be, $\binom{5}{1}*\binom{4}{1}$ + $\binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}$.

For the same colour, it would be, $3(\binom{5}{1}*\binom{3}{1})$.

So answer would be :: $$\frac{\binom{5}{1}*\binom{4}{1} + \binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}+3(\binom{5}{1}*\binom{3}{1})}{\binom{8}{2}}$$

Is this correct? if not, then please help me.

help appreciated. This is my first post so please go easy on me if i did somthing wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of ways to choose $2$ out of $8$ chips is $\binom82=28$.

The number of ways to choose $2$ chips with the same color is $\binom52+\binom32=13$.

The number of ways to choose $2$ chips with the same number is $\min(5,3)=3$.

So the probability to choose $2$ chips with the same color or number is $\frac{3+13}{28}=\frac{4}{7}$.

Comment: but they r drawn without replacement so, if, we pick a red chip we first have $\binom{5}{1}$ ways, then there are just 4 left, so it would be $\binom{4}{1}$. am i wrong? where?

Comment: @ShivamGautam: Think of it as if you pick them at once (and not one at a time).

Comment: but its without replacement, first one, then the other. :( i'm sorry, i'm new to this.

Comment: @ShivamGautam: Picking them at once is also without replacement, but at least it doesn't get you confused as picking them one at a time does. When you pick them one at a time, you later need to divide by $2!$ (or if you pick $n$ items, then by $n!$).

Comment: But if they are the same then the probability should also be, but, $\binom{5}{2}=10$ and $\binom{5}{1} * \binom{4}{1}=20$. how?

Comment: @ShivamGautam: See the comment above. Like I said, when you pick them one at a time, you later need to divide by $2!$ (or if you pick $n$ items, then by $n!$).

Comment: oh ok got it. Thank u

Comment: You're welcome :)